# How to use Union All with Order by to order Date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have stored date in varchar type in sql server 2008 in "dd-MMM-yyyy" format in all tables.
now i am using Union All to combine data of two tables and order it by date in "dd-MM-yyyy" format.
but unfortunately i am not getting it in any ascending or descending order.
please help as soon as possible
Thanks in advance

Comment: hint: you can use functions in the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 3):

You stored the dates wrong. *Don't store dates in varchar columns!*

The fix here is to change your schema to put the dates in datetime columns. Then the ORDER BY is simple.

Moreover, **if** (and that's an *extremely* strong "if", that should really *never* happen) you insist on storing dates as text, at least have the good sense to use a sortable format. Something, say, standard. Something like, I don't know, [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/), that puts each date component in descending order.

Comment: Actually i am not able to change date format because i am an employee of    a company. so i have to do what they tell me to do. and i want to use that date in dd-mm-yyyy format in crystal report to display. and that record should be in specific order.

Comment: Crystal Reports will format the date for you however you want, if you've stored it properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not store `Date` in `Varchar` column as **Joel Coehoorn** suggested. Anyhow, you can try this query

```
-- Converts to date type from varchar, then convert to dd/MM/yyyy and replace / with -
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CAST(DATECOL AS DATE),103),'/','-') 
DATECOL
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE ISDATE(DATECOL)=1
ORDER BY CAST(DATECOL AS DATE)
```

- `ISDATE(DATECOL)=1` will retrieve valid dates from you column. It will be type safe.
- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2661f/2)**

**Note : You need not tell SQL Server to order by in your format. If it of date type, SQL Server will automatically do it when you give `ORDER BY  CAST(DATECOL AS DATE)`**